# Retrieve only necessary data

Tags: json, laravel, api, collections, response

Here is my store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();
    $post->author()->associate(auth()->user());
    $post->fill($request->all());
    $post->save();

    return response()->json($post);
}
```

As a response i get:

[image]

I don't want all the data so I tried to take only the data I have defined like this:

```
$post = $post->only([
    'id',
    'title',
    'content',
    'published_at',
    'author'
]);
```

And response now is:

[image]

Much better, but not completely. I can not define post author data in this way.
The only way is by creating a creepy relationship where you select only necessary data or like this:

```
    $post = [
        'id' => $post->id,
        'title' => $post->title,
        'content' => $post->content,
        'published_at' => $post->published_at->toDateTimeString(),
        'author' => [
            'id' => $post->author->id,
            'name' => $post->author->name,
            'email' => $post->author->email,
        ]
    ];
```

So my question is... maybe there is more elegant way to achieve this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.6....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to just use `only` with the author as well:

```
return $post->only('id', 'title', 'content') + [
        'author' => $post->author->only('id', 'name', 'email'),
    ];
```

If it was going to get any more complicated or reused somewhere else then I would suggest using something like [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources)

Answer (score 1):

I would add a function to your Post model

```
public function jsonOutput()
{
    $array['id'] = $this->id;
    $array['title'] = $this->title;
    $array['content'] = $this->content;
    $array['author'] = [
        'id' => $this->author->id,
        'name' => $this->author->id
    ];

    return $array;
}
```

and then call it like this

```
return response()->json($post->jsonOutput());
```